# Building the Vivarium building in a water city, in Civilization:Beyond Earth - Rising Tide

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth, civ-beyond-earth-rising-tide

I have a quest to build the Vivarium Building in a water city. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Timelord64 The problem is the Vivarium says it can only be built on land cities but my quest SPECIFICALLY says to build it on my city which is a water city.

Comment: I have had this issue with quest buildings with water cities as well. Seems like a bug the dev studio needs to fix. BTW, since water cities only exists in the Rising Tides expansion, you should probably tag this CBE-Rising-Tides or something similar.

Comment: Here's a random idea: Have you tried renaming a land-based city to the name of the city needed in the quest? I suspect you might have to rename your water city first to something different. I have no idea if this would work, and I actually kinda doubt it will. But... it's at least worth a try.